# APPLICATION ERROR: transaction still active in request with status 0

Tags: jbpm

Looks like it is a big bug in JBPM6.5.  If the loop is very big, the process will encounter error "*APPLICATION ERROR: transaction still active in request with status 0*"

I am not sure what happened. Anyone can explain it?  Thanks very much. You can reproduce the error by following steps:

1. download the workflow file into your project.
   https://github.com/kylinsoong/jBPM-Drools-Example/blob/master/jbpm/quickstarts/src/main/resources/quickstarts/looping.bpmn
2. change the variable "count" to a big number in "Init" step, eg. 50000, 
   [see  screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtXEQ.png)
3. deploy your project.
4. run the  workflow "looping",  the error will come up.